# "Trying to get property of non-object " After uploading a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have just added a .csv file to the database of a site I'm working on, and am now greeted with: 
*"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\napier_pull\index.php on line 254"*

I initially tested the page by adding a CSV file with sample/junk data on it and it worked fine, the only difference with this file is that there are empty cells within the sheet, could that be what has gone wrong?

The code in question:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT title, description, class, details, related1, related2, related3, related1_link, related2_link, related3_link, linktitle_1, linktitle_2, linktitle_3, linktitle_1_desc, linktitle_2_desc, linktitle_3_desc, linktitle_1_url, linktitle_2_url, linktitle_3_url FROM relevant_topics";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $title_clean = $row["title"];
    $title_clean = strtolower($title_clean);
    $title_clean = preg_replace('/\s*/', '', $title_clean);        
    echo'<div class="col-lg-4">
         <div class="mix item '.$row["class"].'">
         <h3>'.$row["title"].'</h3>
         <p>'.$row["description"].'</p>
         </br>
         <p>Related Items:</p>
         <p>
         <a href="'.$row["related1_link"].'">'.$row["related1"].',</a> &nbsp;
         <a href="'.$row["related2_link"].'">'.$row["related2"].',</a> &nbsp;
         <a href="'.$row["related3_link"].'">'.$row["related3"].',</a> </p>
         </br>
         <div class="item-bottom">
         <a href="#myModal'.$title_clean.'" role="button" data-toggle="modal">See more lad</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Line 254 is this line:

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: `var_dump($result)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: The result is either an object or false in this case. So no need for it.

Comment: Please do `var_dump($conn->error, $conn->errno);` after `$result = $conn->query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

`$result` is probably `NULL` because there was an error executing your query. You should check errors with `$conn->error` and/or `$conn->errno` after `$conn->query(...)`.

Comment: The data was successfully uploaded to the database though, and going through the table on phpMyAdmin it seems fine aside from some blank cells. 
Added $conn->error and got "0 results"

Comment: `$conn->error` gives you an empty string or a error message, but not `0 results`.

Comment: Where do I put it? Tried this :     $result = $conn->error();

Comment: See my comment under your question.